Show that $\text{TOT} \equiv_m \text{INF}$.
Let $\text{INF} = \{x \in \mathbb{N}:\operatorname{Dom}\phi_x\text{ is infinite}\}$ and
$\text{TOT} = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : \operatorname{Dom}\phi_x = \mathbb{N}\}$. We need to show that
$$\text{INF} \equiv_m \text{TOT}$$
where for sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}$ we have $A \equiv_m B$ iff there exists partially computable functions
$f, g$ such that $f^{-1}(A) = B$ and $g^{-1}(B) = A$, where $f^{-1}$ denotes the pre-image of $f$.
When trying to come up with programs that may show what we want, the main issue I come up with is trying to check in the program that $\operatorname{Dom}(\phi_x)$ is infinite or is $\mathbb{N}$. For example, I thought about a program representing a partially computable function
$f$ that does the following

Take the input $X \in \text{TOT}$
Then do $X \leftarrow X + 1$ (append 1 to $X$)
Check if $\operatorname{Dom}{\phi_{X+1}}$ is infinite
If it is, then stop and return the new $X$

But I failed because I couldn't find a way to compute the checking of the condition.
Any hints/solutions would be highly appreciated!

What is $\phi_x$ here?

It represents the function computed by program with code $x$.

You don't need to computably "check" the domains are infinite/total. You need a total computable function $f$ such that $\phi_{x}\in \mathrm{INF}\iff \phi_{f(x)}\in \rm TOT.$ (And similarly for the other direction.)
We have $\phi_x\in\rm INF$ if and only if $\forall n\exists m>n\;\phi_x(m)\downarrow.$ So how about we define $f$ so that $\phi_{f(x)}(n)\downarrow$ iff there is an $m>n$ such that $\phi_x(m)\downarrow$? I'll leave it up to you to convince yourself that this can be accomplished by a computable function $f$ (essentially, we just need to have $\phi_{f(x)}$ "search for such an $m$" and halt if and when it finds one).
Similarly, for the other direction, arrange that $\phi_{f(x)}(n)\downarrow$ if and only if $\phi_x(m)\downarrow$ for all $m\le n.$
